# Javascript Function Not Executed Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an app that uses HTML & JavaScript, and it isnt working correctly.
A video that describes the bug:

http://vk.com/video170263591_169020196

And the code goes like this:

```
function load() {
    $("#Load").show(0,function(){
        console.log('Spinner Loaded');
    });
}
function unload() {
    $("#Load").hide();
    console.log('Load Ended');
}
function server(datasend) {
    var response;
    var postURL = "http://mailsnitch.ipx-il.com/get/index.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: postURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout:4000,
        async: false,
        data: datasend,
        beforeSend : load(),
        success: function(valueable){
            console.log('Success');
            response = valueable;
            console.log(valueable);
            unload();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            console.log('Error');
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 502) {
                alert('Bad Gateway [502].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
            unload();
        },
    });
    return response;
}
```

And the log in function:

```
function Login(redirect) {
    load();
    if(redirect) {
        var email = escapeHtml(document.getElementById("Login_email").value);
        var password = escapeHtml(document.getElementById("Login_password").value);
    } else {
        if(localStorage.getItem("Email") == null) document.location.href = 'login.html';
        var email = escapeHtml(localStorage["Email"]);
        var password = escapeHtml(localStorage["Password"]);
    }
    if(email != "" && password != "") {
        if(validateEmail(email)) {
            var valuable = server('login=&email='+email+'&password='+password);
```

The problem is:
When loading the "Login" function, the Load function should run, but it isnt running.
even though the functions order is:

load()

server() {
 before: load();
 and than do ajax...
}

Within the console, I can see that the "load successful" shows exactly at the same milisecond as "ajax success", which means that the load is waiting for the ajax to load before doing the function.

Thx for helpers.

Comment: Please provide a better title that describes your problem.

Comment: @adeneo Im doing this async because that if im not doing it async, the veriable "valueable" is undefind instantly, and I need it to first read the ajax and than to do the checks i need and so on...

Comment: That's what promises are for, you need to work around the asynchronous nature of ajax, not just turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the function immediately, not referencing it, it should be

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: postURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout:4000,
    async: false,
    data: datasend,
    beforeSend : load,

    ....
```

adding the parenthesis calls the function and returns the result, which is `undefined`, which is what the `$.ajax` call sees.

Also note that setting `async : false` defeats the entire purpose of Asynchronous Javascript And XML, as you just made it synchronous instead.

**EDIT**

your code should look something more like this

```
function load() {
    $("#Load").show();
}
function unload() {
    $("#Load").hide();
}

function server(datasend) {
    return $.ajax({
        type       : 'POST',
        url        : "http://mailsnitch.ipx-il.com/get/index.php",
        dataType   : 'json',
        timeout    : 4000,
        data       : datasend,
        beforeSend : load
    });
}

function Login(redirect) {
    if(redirect) {
        var email    = escapeHtml(document.getElementById("Login_email").value);
        var password = escapeHtml(document.getElementById("Login_password").value);
    } else {
        if(localStorage.getItem("Email") == null) {
            document.location.href = 'login.html';
        }
        var email    = escapeHtml(localStorage["Email"]);
        var password = escapeHtml(localStorage["Password"]);
    }
    if(email != "" && password != "") {
        if(validateEmail(email)) {

            server({login : '', email: email, password: password}).done(function(valuable) {

                // use valuable here

            }).always(unload);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working either. if you need to see for yourself:
http://vk.com/video170263591_169020357
(The Token error is irelevant for being in an entirely different page.)

Comment: now it is loading before executing, but also before executing it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined 
on the line:

server({login : '', email: email, password: password}).done(function(valuable) {

so the code is executing before it is acctualy done...

Comment: Did you type it as in the answer, where `server()` returns `$.ajax`